# How to convert from EFI to MBR boot loader (and / or GPT disk to MBR disk) in Arch Linux without losing data

Tags: hard-drive, uefi, bootloader, mbr, gpt

I've installed arch linux on my disk sdc,where sdc1 is the efi partition and sdc2 the root partition. I'm also trying to boot this installation with esxi 7,but it seems that it refuses to boot because it says that it can't find the PARTUUID number that I use to boot it physically,as u can see below :

[image]
[image]

I'm not able to understand what's the right value to use,so I've thought that for a newbie like me it was easier to convert the EFI bootloader of arch linux to the mbr bootloader (and / or the whole GPT to MBR hard drive),without loosing the data and without to make a new installation. Maybe,doing this operation,esxi will be able to boot the arch linux. thanks.

UPDATE :

The solution is to modify the file /etc/fstab,changing /dev/sdc1 with /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdc2 with /dev/sda2.

Comment: Your question is confusing EFI cannot be compared to MBR.

Comment: what you are suggesting me to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your VM got to this point, then your current bootloader type and partition table type are suitable, as indeed your've successfully loaded the kernel and reached the Linux initramfs. The error message is not from ESXi nor from your bootloader, but from Linux itself.

Most likely, the "physical" disk emulated by ESXi is of a different type than the one you have (e.g. SCSI vs AHCI vs NVMe) and the initramfs archive is missing the correct driver for it. Try editing the kernel command line to use `initramfs-linux-fallback.img` which always includes all drivers.

You can also take a look at `dmesg` to check what kind of disks are being detected by Linux. If the initramfs includes it, also try `lsblk` (possibly `lsblk -o +partuuid`).

Comment: almost worked,but not totally. give a look at this pic : https://ibb.co/XxjFNL3

Comment: Your disk was "sdc" outside, but it is not called "sdc" inside ESXi (it might be sdb, vda, nvme0, or whatever). Fix your /etc/fstab to refer to partitions by their UUIDs or PARTUUIDs instead.

Comment: The solution is to modify the file /etc/fstab,changing /dev/sdc1 with /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdc2 with /dev/sda2.

Comment: No, that's a one-time workaround that's more likely to break in the exact same way than not. The solution is to modify /etc/fstab to use UUIDs or PARTUUIDs.